# MySQL list entities and applying AND filter on joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

There are two tables: Person, House
House has a FK to Person called person_id
House has a field called city

Is there a way to list all Person with a House in both city_a and city_b? This should exclude people with only houses in one of the city but include people who has houses in both and also additional cities.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT person.* 
FROM Person person 
JOIN House house ON house.person_id = person.id 
WHERE house.city IN ("city_a", "city_b");
```

However, this query only returns list of people who have houses in either city_a or city_b, so it doesn't satisfy the AND condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method uses `exists` . . . twice:

```
select p.*
from person p
where exists (select 1 from house h where h.person_id = p.id and h.city = 'city_a') and
      exists (select 1 from house h where h.person_id = p.id and h.city = 'city_b') ;
```

If you just wanted the ids of the person, then `group by` and `having` are convenient:

```
select h.person_id
from house h
where h.city in ('city_a', 'city_b')
group by h.person_id
having count(distinct h.city) = 2
```